# Thales theorem and relation

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I am trying to help my brother who's taken up Math as a hobby with a problem he can't solve, but I'm stuck on it myself.

It goes like this:

We take a point `D` on the side `AB` of an `ABC` triangle such that `AD:DB = 3:5`, and a point `E` on the side `CD` such that `CE:ED = 2:3`. If `AE` crosses `BC` at the point `F`, what is the relation `BF:FC`.

The answer is `5:12`, but I can't figure out how to use Thales' theorem to get it.

Comment: `The answer is 5:12` Not sure about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:   [Menelaus' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelaus%27s_theorem) for $\,\triangle BCD\,$ and transversal $\,AF\,$ gives $\,\dfrac{BF}{FC} \cdot \dfrac{CE}{ED} \cdot \dfrac{DA}{AB} = 1\,$. 
You know $\,\dfrac{CE}{ED}=\dfrac{2}{3}\,$ and $\,\dfrac{DA}{AB} = \ldots\,$

Comment: That looks good, but I'm not sure they've yet studiied Menelaus' theorem in the 9th grade, so it'd be hard for me to explain it to him.

Comment: @user8814 The [proof of Menelaus' theorem](http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/emt725/Menelaus/Menelaus.html) is rather elementary. On the other hand, I don't see how [Thales' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem) could apply here without somehow proving an equivalent of Menelaus' in disguise.

Comment: Oh wow, that proof really clears it up. I'll have to demonstrate it to him and ease him into it, and show him how it applies to this case. Geometry intimidates him, as he is used to Algebra, and having a straightforward road to his answer. Thank you so much for the help!